# Pandas dataframe transformation

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Could someone help me transform the below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1], 'B':[2,2,2], 'C':['1y', '3y', '7y'], 'D':[111,222,333], 'E':[-111,-222,-333]})
print(df1)
```

into this form:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1], 'B':[2], 'D_1y':[111], 'D_3y':[222], 'D_7y':[333], 'E_1y':[-111], 'E_3y':[-222], 'E_7y':[-333]})
print(df2)
```

This is a small sample from a huge dataframe, I have several columns like 'D' and 'E' all of which are linked to column 'C'.

Comment: Sorry but pivot will not work here, I have several columns like 'D'.

Comment: `df2 = df1.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], columns='C')`

Comment: `df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')`

Comment: @jezrael thanks, trying these now.